# Python 3.6.2 url.request.urlopen() urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to scrape some data off of Google Finances' website as a practise using Python 3.6.2. This is the code:

```
import urllib.request
url="https://www.google.com/search?num=40&newwindow=1&tbm=fin&q="
stockName=input("The stock you want to search for:")
url=url+stockName
url="https://www.google.com/search?num=40&newwindow=1&tbm=fin&q=FB"
data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()`
```

But I kept getting HTTP error 403.
The error I got was like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#101>", line 1, in <module>
data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
                      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 564, in error
result = self._call_chain(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 756, in http_error_302
return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

What should I do? Before this, I got an SSL Certificate Error, but that was solved due to a finding an answer in this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sites do not necessarily support headless scraping, whether it is due to missing proper headers or missing JS support to prevent bots.  It'll return a 403 status or something else other than what you expected.  I'm not familiar enough with `urllib` to comment on, but when I try it with the `requests` module, it seems to work.

```
import requests
res = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?num=40&newwindow=1&tbm=fin&q=FB")
res.raise_for_status()

# No status raised
```

You might also want to try to `urllib2`.  Both libraries I've mentioned you'll need to install from `pip`.

A solution for `urllib` exists.  You'll need to add the header manually.  Personally I use `fake_useragent` library (again, install from pip) to spoof headers:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from urllib import request

ua = UserAgent()
req = request.Request("https://www.google.com/search?num=40&newwindow=1&tbm=fin&q=FB")
req.add_header('User-Agent', ua.chrome)
data = request.urlopen(req)
```

You can, if you're familiar enough, set up your own User-Agent string without using `fake_useragent`.  In which case simply replace the `ua.chrome` portion with your User-Agent strings.  As you can see though, `requests` work without even needing a header in this case - if you're up for increasing your skillset, that's a viable option that might save you some headaches in the future.

**Edit:** Just to add my personal experience.  One good way I've found debugging these issues is to save the page your code have retrieved and compare it to what you see in an actual browser.  This way you'll know if some contents are JS driven (and therefore cannot be parsed by a simple scrape) or if you are receiving something different entirely (which means your scrap is missing some elements the page is expecting, e.g. headers or JS support).

Comment: I tried using requests, but it doesn't work with 3.6.2

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work though, what are you getting as a result? Either way perhaps the `urllib` solution can help you then.

Comment: I can't find the urllib2 module. Every time I try to import it, it just doesn't work. Errors keep popping out.

Comment: Again, what do you mean it doesn't work, not being specific is not helping you or me here.  Maybe you should [read up on how to install packages with pip first](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)